# Como traer el dato que sea menor o igual a un parámetro con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

tengo la siguiente tabla en mi base de datos:

Tabla: especial - Esta tabla esta llena de valores que serian parámetros para que al llenar el formulario de index.php podamos luego comparar con los parámetros de la tabla especial y de esa forma nos de un valor en especifico dependiendo de los valores insertados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta compuesta por 5 columnas.

id
c
a
r
valorfinal

Por otro lado tengo un formulario de ingreso de valores:

index.php

```
<form action="insertar.php" method="POST">

<input type="text" name="valorc" placeholder="Ingrese Valor C">

<input type="text" name="valora" placeholder="Ingrese Valor A">

<input type="text" name="valorr" placeholder="Ingrese Valor R">


<br><br>

<input type="submit" value="GUARDAR VALORES"/>
 
</form>
```

Los campos del formulario los guarda bien en otra tabla lo que estoy buscando hacer es lo siguiente:

Adjunte una imagen con los valores que actualmente tiene la tabla (especial)
La idea es que si en el formulario de index.php inserto lo siguiente:

valorc = 60
valora = 50
valorr = 100

debe traer en otro input el valor que corresponda a esa combinación. El valor seria = 165

La forma en que debería funcionar el algoritmo es que los valores del formulario index.php deben ser menores o iguales a los parámetros de la tabla especial.

Esta es mi consulta pero no funciona como lo necesito:

```
<?php 

//Aquí traigo los valores que se insertaron por medio del formulario de index.php

    $c=$datosone['valorc'];
    $a=$datosone['valora'];
    $r=$datosone['valorr'];
    

//Aquí le digo a mi consulta que me traiga el (valor que debe traer) mientras sea menor o igual a lo registrado en la tabla especial. 
    
    $cond=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from `especial` where c<='$c' AND a<='$a' AND r<='$r'");
    $condicione = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cond);
    
    $valorfinal=$condicione['valorfinal'];


?>

//y luego por aquí imprimo el valor que trae.

<input type="text" id="final" name="final" value="<?php echo $valorfinal?>" />
```

El problema es que me trae los valores que no son.

Les dejo un par de ejercicios para ver si lo entienden mejor:

Si

valorc = 30
valora = 80
valorr = 130

Deberia traer como valorfinal = 175 de la tabla especial ya que todos los valores deben ser menor o igual a los que están registrados. deben hacer match.

Preguntaran porque trae el valorfinal 175
Si nos fijamos el valorc es igual a 30 entonces quiere decir que seria la primera fila
Si nos fijamos en el valora es igual a 80 que corresponde a la sefunda fila
Si nos fijamos en el valorr es igual a 130 que seria menor a 150 que se encuentra en la tercera fila

Por ende como valorr se encuentra en el rango 130 que seria menor a 150 el se posiciona allí, ya que si toma como principal el valorc que seria 30 no corresponde con el valor ingresado.

Cualquier ayuda que me puedan aportar me seria de gran utilidad, si no entendieron algo quedo atento para poder explicarlo mejor.

Muchas gracias amigos.

Comment: Hola, son campos numéricos

Answer (score 0):

En un primer intento, modificaría estas líneas:

```
$c=$datosone['valorc'];
$a=$datosone['valora'];
$r=$datosone['valorr'];
$cond=mysqli_query($conn,"
    select * from `especial` 
      where c<='$c' AND a<='$a' AND r<='$r';
");
```

Por:

```
$c=$_POST['valorc'];
$a=$_POST['valora'];
$r=$_POST['valorr'];
$cond=mysqli_query($conn,"
    select * from `especial` 
      where c>=$c AND a>=$a AND r>=$r
      order by valorfinal;
");
```

Prueba así, y me cuentas qué obtienes. Únicamente he utilizado la variable superglobal `$_POST` para obtener los valores del formulario y he prescindido de las comillas simples para que el servidor MySQL pueda hacer la comparación numérica. Por otra parte, estabas haciendo la comparación al revés, `c<=$c` implica que el valor de formulario, `$c`, sea mayor al de la tabla, `c`, y lo que necesitas es lo contario.

Lo que no me ha quedado del todo claro es por qué `175` y no `185`, que también lo cumple. De ahí que te lo haya ordenado con `order by`, intuyendo que buscas el número `valorfinal` más bajo que lo cumpla.

Te invito a que explores `mysqli_prepare()` para evitar SQL injection.

Comment: Hola @David JP ya hice lo que mencionaste pero un sigue sin funcionarme bien la consulta.

Comment: ¿En qué falla? ¿Obtienes algún mensaje de error o el comportamiento no es el esperado?

Comment: El comportamiento no es el esperado @David JP , que otra solución podria implementar?

Comment: No me dices qué obtienes en lugar de lo que esperas, pero intuyo que, con las condiciones que estableces en el `WHERE`, no te venga ningún valor, porque ningún registro de la tabla cumple la condición que has programado. Por tus explicaciones, el error está en el sentido de los comparadores: `<=` en vez de `>=`. Así he modificado la respuesta. Ya me confirmas...